# Models inheritance in django: getting OneToMany objects from parent class

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

Here is model structure: Client is User, Client can be corporate or person:

```
class Client(User):
    #fields

class ClientCorporate(Client):
    #fields


class ClientPerson(Client):
    #fields
```

And client can make orders:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client)
    #fields
```

I try to create common orders list for any type of client, here is view:

```
def orders_list(request):
    client=request.user.client
    return list_detail.object_list(request,
        queryset = client.order_set.all(),
        #templates ...
        )
```

And it leads to an error:

**DatabaseError while rendering: no such column: cabinets_order.client_id**

I browse db and find that all User childs have column "user_prt_id". So, what's the best way to make it work in django? Create custom manager, or change models in appropriate way? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error just means you don't have the database column `client_id` in your `cabinets_order` table.

Make sure you `python manage.py syncdb`. If you added the foreign key after `syncdb`ing once, you'll have to reset it, or add the foreign key manually. You can generate the SQL needed by running `python manage.py sqlall cabinets`, then picking the ForeignKey generation bits.

If you can stand to lose your current data (if in development), just run `python manage.py reset cabinets`